# Element-wise positive-part of PSD matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

My question is the following. Suppose I have a matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ symmetric and positive semi-definite. I consider the now the matrix $A_+$ defined as 
$$
(A_+)_{i,j} = \begin{cases} A_{ij} & \text{if } A_{ij}\geq 0 \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}
$$ 
Is it true that $A_+$ is also positive semi definite?

Answer (score 3):

This is not generally true.  For instance:
$$
A = \pmatrix{10 & 3 & -2 & 1\\
3 & 10 & 0 & 9\\
-2 & 0 & 10 & 4\\
1 & 9 & 4 & 10}, \qquad
A_+ = \pmatrix{10 & 3 & 0 & 1\\
3 & 10 & 0 & 9\\
0 & 0 & 10 & 4\\
1 & 9 & 4 & 10}
$$
You may verify that $A$ is strictly positive definite, while $A_+$ fails to be positive semidefinite (in fact, $A_+$ has negative determinant $\det(A_+) = -16$).

*This example was stolen from Horn and Johnson's "Matrix Analysis", 2nd edition, problem 7.5.P6.  In that context, this matrix is used to show that $|A|$ (the matrix resulting from taking the absolute values of entries) need not be positive semidefinite when $A$ is positive semidefinite.*

Comment: Do you know if there are any $3\times3$ counterexamples, or is this the smallest possible? It is not possible for $2\times2$ matrices, obviously.

Comment: @Rahul I am not sure. My gut feeling is that this example is minimal in some sense: by the convexity of the PSD matrices, finding an example for $A_+$ would mean that there exists a counterexample for $|A|$.  Since H+J choose to present this example, I imagine that there are no convenient $3 \times 3$ examples for $|A|$, which would necessarily mean that there are no convenient $3 \times 3$ examples for $A_+$.

Comment: Your argument, while not conclusive, is compelling.